# how to disable rsh and rlogin service on debian 7.8

Tags: iptables, inetd

I want to disable rsh and rlogin. I have disable 513 and 154 port in iptables,but I still can login with rsh on another host.I'm working on Debian7.8 32bit

my /etc/inetd.conf is here

```
# /etc/inetd.conf:  see inetd(8) for further informations.
#
# Internet superserver configuration database
#
#
# Lines starting with "#:LABEL:" or "#<off>#" should not 
# be changed unless you know what you are doing!
#
# If you want to disable an entry so it isn't touched during
# package updates just comment it out with a single '#' character.
#
# Packages should modify this file by using update-inetd(8)
#
# <service_name> <sock_type> <proto> <flags> <user> <server_path> <args>
#
#:INTERNAL: Internal services
#discard        stream  tcp nowait  root    internal
#discard        dgram   udp wait    root    internal
#daytime        stream  tcp nowait  root    internal
#time       stream  tcp nowait  root    internal

#:STANDARD: These are standard services.

#:BSD: Shell, login, exec and talk are BSD protocols.

#:MAIL: Mail, news and uucp services.

#:INFO: Info services

#:BOOT: TFTP service is provided primarily for booting.  Most sites
#       run this only on machines acting as "boot servers."

#:RPC: RPC based services

#:HAM-RADIO: amateur-radio services

#:OTHER: Other services
#<off># netbios-ssn stream  tcp nowait  root    /usr/sbin/tcpd  /usr/sbin/smbd
swat        stream  tcp nowait.400  root    /usr/sbin/tcpd  /usr/sbin/swat
#<off># sane-port   stream  tcp nowait  saned:saned /usr/sbin/saned saned
```

Comment: I think this question is more suited the https://serverfault.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `disable` field in the configuration file `/etc/xinetd.d/rlogin` and `/etc/xinetd.d/rsh`
Then use the command `service xinetd restart` to restart the xinetd service

Comment: I don't have those files on my machine.I got the answer on [serverFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/886579/disable-‌​rsh-login-on-sshd-se‌​rver?noredirect=1#co‌​mment1143459_886579). In short rsh/rlogin is a link to ssh